# What is the connnection between "jet-space" and algebro-geometric deformation theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Charles Doran, wrote an annoted bibliography on deformation theory that
is available from him via email (I have asked him the question below via email). In it one finds the quotation:

> Grothendieck's fundamental observation was that the ring-theoretic 
>   analogue of geometric “jet-space” constructions is a representation of
>   the corresponding functor by Artinian rings.

I am thinking that this refers to the second installment of Grothendieck's FGA Bourbaki Seminaire note: http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SB_1958-1960__5__369_0 ? I guess I am looking for a kind GAGA like dictionary that motivates Grothendieck's introduction of pro-representable functors as a substitute for the analytic Kodaira-Spencer theory?

The question [Deformation theory and differential graded Lie algebras](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385/deformation-theory-and-differential-graded-lie-algebras)
looks vaguely useful.

Comment: You can also have a look at Grothendieck's exposes at Seminaire Henri Cartan (13), exp. 7-17, 1960-61, Techniques de construction en geometrie analytique I-X.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I actually am in the process of examining those documents. I gather they deal with Grothendieck's viewpoint on Teichm\"uller theory?